# Print text at specified line number bash

Tags: bash

I want to print the text at a specified line number from a file.

Here is my bash script

```
line=12
sed -n "$line{p;q;}"
```

My line number comes in a variable. But the above code is not working. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
line=12
sed -n "${line}p" my_file

# Multiple lines
line1=10
line2=15
sed -n "${line1},${line2}p" my_file
```

In `awk`:

```
awk "NR==${line}" my_file

# Multiple lines
awk "NR >= ${line1} && NR <= ${line2}" my_file
```

Or using `head` and `tail` but probably not as efficient:

```
head -${line} my_file | tail -1

# Multiple lines    
head -${line2} my_file | tail -$(($line2-$line1+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the file name as an argument to `sed`.

```
line=12
sed -n "$line{p;q;}" filename
```

If you are passing the filename as an argument to a bash script, you need to use:

```
line=12
sed -n "$line{p;q;}" "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast sed command (useful for bigger files) is:

```
n=12; sed $n'q;d' file
```